# How can I locate this element with selenium webdriver?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, testing

This should be so simple but I'm obviously missing something:

```
<div>
    <label>
        Scenario
        <select id="scenarios">
            <option value="0">Default (Visa)</option>
            <option value="1">Secondary (Amex)</option>
        </select>
        <button onclick="pickScenario()">Select</button>
    </label>

    <label style="padding-left: 2em;">
        Custom Amount: $
        <input type="text" id="custom_amount">
    </label>
</div>
```

I keep getting `NullPointerExceptions` returned when trying to locate any of the three elements (scenarioDropdown, selectButton, customAmount) using the code below. I've tried all three with id, xpath, and css but below I'm showing one way per element:

```
  @FindBy(css = "#scenarios")
  private WebElement scenariosDropdown;

  @FindBy(xpath = "//button[contains(.,'Select')]")
  private WebElement select;

  @FindBy(how = How.ID, using = "custom_amount")
  private WebElement customAmount;

  private WebDriver driver;

  public void selectScenario(String scenario) {

    Select select = new Select(scenariosDropdown);
    select.deselectAll();
    select.selectByVisibleText(scenario);
  }

  void clickSelect() {
    select.click();
  }

  public void enterCustomAmount(String amount) {
    customAmount.clear();
    customAmount.sendKeys(amount);
  }
```

Running a test that uses the method below.

```
  public void testWhileBroken() {

    // select Scenario Two
    cc.selectScenario("Secondary (Amex)");

    // enter a Custom Amount
    cc.enterCustomAmount("1.23");

    // click Select
    cc.clickSelect();

  }
```

And it returns :

> Aug 16, 2017 9:07:16 AM org.openqa.selenium.remote.ProtocolHandshake
>   createSession INFO: Detected dialect: OSS
>
> java.lang.NullPointerException    at
>   org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.(Select.java:44)  at
>   apps.web.modules.staplespay.CreditCardsScreen.selectScenario(CreditCardsScreen.java:27)

What is the super obvious thing that I'm missing here?

Comment: Which package you have imported for `Select` class ?

Comment: how are you creating the object `cc`

Comment: @Tuks import org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select;

Comment: @GaurangShah the select.., enter.. and click.. methods are in a class temporarily called CreditCardProcessing so cc comes from CreditCardsScreen cc = new CreditCardsScreen();

Comment: and how does the constructor looks `CreditCardsScreen()`

Comment: @rHenderson, If any answer helpful to you then please `accept` it So it be helpful for others

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your `testWhileBroken()` method looks good to me. (Lets assume the Class name is `ABC.class`)

But the reason you are facing `java.lang.NullPointerException at org.openqa.selenium.support.ui.Select.(Select.java:44)` is because in your `PageFactory` class (let us assume the Class name is `XYZ.class`) you have only declared the instance of the `WebDriver` as:

```
private WebDriver driver;
```

As far as **`PageFactory`** with **`POM`** is concerned, we must initialize the page objects in the test class (i.e. in `ABC.class`) by calling the **`initElements()`** method where you pass the instance of the **`WebDriver`** i.e. **`driver`** as an argument as follows:

```
//ABC.class
@Test (priority=2)
public void method_name()
{
    //Initialize page objects
    XYZ xyz = PageFactory.initElements(driver, XYZ.class);

    //Call the method
    xyz.my_method();
}
```

Now, in the page object class (i.e. in `XYZ.class`) along with declaring an instance of the `WebDriver`, additionally you have to define a constructor as follows:

```
//XYZ.class
WebDriver driver;

//constructor
public XYZ(WebDriver XYZDriver)
{
    this.driver=XYZDriver;
}
```

This will take care of the **`NullPointerException`**

Answer (score 0):

You are missing the driver to pass in page class constructor. So it is not finding the driver and throw the NullPointerException :

Expected code would be :

```
public class TestClass
{

    // all your webelements
    public TestClass(WebDriver driver)
    {
        PageFactory.initElements(driver, this);

     }
     // all your intended function

}
```

And in your test executor class make sure you have instantiated the webdriver  and pass it at the time of object creation like

```
CreditCardsScreen cc = new CreditCardsScreen(driver);

 public void testWhileBroken() {

    // select Scenario Two
    cc.selectScenario("Secondary (Amex)");

    // enter a Custom Amount
    cc.enterCustomAmount("1.23");

    // click Select
    cc.clickSelect();

  }
```

Answer (score 0):

or the alternate solution is to change the way you are creating the object for pages. 
change this:

```
CreditCardsScreen cc = new CreditCardsScreen();
```

to:

```
CreditCardsScreen cc = PageFactory.initElements(driver, CreditCardsScreen.class);
```